# Android background not correctly applied on first instance

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-support-library

I have a very simple layout, simply two buttons below each other. On both buttons I set a drawable layer-list as background, containing the selectableItemBackground causing a ripple effect on the buttons.

A weird bug occurs: on the first button, the ripple effect doesn't happen, but on the second button it does. How can this be explained, or can it be a bug in Android/Support Libraries?

Setting clickhandlers doesn't change anything, the behaviour stays the same.

See example gif below, and XML code below that.

[image: GIF of behaviour]

main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/first_button"
        android:text="First Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_selectable_button"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/second_button"
        android:text="Second Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_selectable_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

white_selectable_button.xml (in res/drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
    <item android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
</layer-list>
```

It appears that this drawable is applied to the button, since when setting the color to red, the button actually appears red. Only the selectableItemBackground ripple isn't applied.

I've tested this with design support libraries 24.1.1, 23.4.0 and 23.2.0, on all versions, this doesn't change anything.

EDIT: Filed bug report to Android bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took your code and confirmed it also does not work on my device. I submitted this as a [bug against the Android Support Library](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219630&thanks=219630&ts=1470751175). So eventually it will get fixed.

In the meantime, I figured out an easy workaround to fix the bug. All you need to do is add an invisible dummy Button before the other two as it appears this bug only affects the first button. You can eventually remove this once its fixed by Google.

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_selectable_button"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: I didn't add any click listeners to the code, not to the first or the second. My MainActivity is pretty much empty except for the setContentView. Not at my computer right now, so can't test the effect of setting click listeners. I did set them in the original code, that did not have an effect. About your second suggestion, from the top of my head it's version 23.4.0, but I'll need to check that. What version would you suggest? (I will check if this problem occurs when using an older version)

Comment: I've tested some of your suggestions, no results:

1) Click listeners don't matter, with and without them the behaviour is the same. 

2) I've also tested with different support libraries, the problem occurs in the newest 24.1.1, but also in 23.4.0 and 23.2.0.